# Grouping row data in a bootstrap table into a single long row

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular app where i am using a bootstrap table to display list data using ng-repeat.I have repeated data in few rows, How do i include them as one long prolonged row of groups? How do i group multiple rows into a single row for selected columns with groups. I have a flat JSON data coming from server.

The data I am getting from server is similar to the one in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5bnFSINw34abqlM0nvt?p=preview).

I want under Group1 -Just 3 rows clubbing each of the repetitive data and under Group2 two prolonged rows with 1 and 2. How do i achieve this?

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ItemNo</th>
        <th>Group1</th>
        <th>Group2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/J5bnFSINw34abqlM0nvt?p=preview